# How can I test my Ruby CLI app while still in development?

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface

Morning guys,

I am writing a small Ruby CLI app for myself, and I have run into a small issue that I hope you guys can help with. Apologies if this is a stupid question, I am very new to Ruby.

I am using https://github.com/davetron5000/gli as a foundation to build my my app since they make it easy to have all my commands and whatnot.

Question is, while I develop the app, I can run it using `bundle exec bin/konstruct`, but that only works from the folder where the code lies.

I want to run the app from a test folder so I can see whether the code I'm adding is doing what it should (make files, remove files, see if directory is empty, etc).

When I played around with NodeJS, I could link the app, and it would work anywhere. Is there something like that for Ruby apps that are still in development?

Comment: You could use the command `irb` to open a ruby console. Inside the ruby console, you could `require` all your files.  Then you could run your functions in the console.

Comment: Okay, will google around to try this out. Sorry, VERY new to Ruby, and generally still a bit of a n00b at programming (designer)

Answer (score 0):

Two simple way:
1. Make `bin/konstruct` executable. So you can run it without `bundle exec`. Then link it in any directory in your `$PATH` with `ln -s`. (For Unix based systems)
2. Create a alias in your shell. something like this:

```
alias konstruct="bundle exec /FULL/PATH/TO/bin/konstruct"
```

(Also for Unix based systems)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did item 2, and it worked, but I get the following error:

Rincewind:~ traaidmark$ konstruct
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory