# Struggling to run my ruby cli app

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface

I built a small Cli app in ruby (first ever ruby app), but I'm not able to actually run it.

I started the project off with `bundle gem`. I have been testing it inside my apps folder by running `bundle exec bin/konstruct` and everything works fine.

I want to install it locally and test it before I submit it, and so I ran `bundle exec rake install` after updating all of the info in my gemspec file. It gave successfull output:

```
konstruct 0.1.1 built to pkg/konstruct-0.1.1.gem.
konstruct (0.1.1) installed.
```

But when I run the app by entering `$ konstruct` it gives me an `Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory` error, unless I run it from within the root folder of the app.

I have tried to Google but I can't pin the results down to the same issue as I'm having. I've been having this problem even in development ([How can I test my Ruby CLI app while still in development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34626386/how-can-i-test-my-ruby-cli-app-while-still-in-development))

I do have a Gemfile and it contains:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Specify your gem's dependencies in konstruct.gemspec
gemspec
```

I don't have a .bundle/ folder though. I'm not sure where/how that folder should be generated. I have run `bundle` and `bundle install` many times now.

I have a konstruct.gemspec file which contains: https://github.com/konstruct/konstruct.cli/blob/master/konstruct.gemspec

Most of that file is as it was generated. I just filled it in where I could.

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I am super stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following line in your gemspec:

```
spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^exe/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
```

I believe that means if you move your executable file into an `exe` directory instead of a `bin` directory, it will work as you expect.

http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#executables

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but I'm not quite with you. I did change my gemspec file to now have

`  spec.files         = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0").reject { |f| f.match(%r{^(test|spec|features)/}) }
  spec.bindir        = "bin"
  spec.executables << 'konstruct'
  spec.require_paths << 'lib'`

But it is still not working.

Comment: I have done what you suggested but this breaks the app completely.

When I add a dummy exe folder with my script in it, it still gives the same error.

Comment: @TraaidMark I've cloned your repo, `cd`'d to the repo, ran `bundle install` then I ran `bundle exec rake install` and I tried executing the `konstruct` command. It successfully ran (although it gave an error saying `invalid command. Use --help for more information` probably because you haven't added any options yet). No warnings about lack of Gemfiles. What OS are you using?

Comment: @Simpleton Were you able to execute the konstruct command from outside the konstruct folder? For example `cd /some/random/folder` and the running `konstruct`?

I am using OSX Yosemite and using ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I am a first class idiot. Some time ago I added Konstruct in my .path file, which obviously was now overriding the proper konstruct command. Back then what I did din't work, so I just forgot about it.

So the answer to this question: It's not broken. OP is an idiot. :-/